# Forward event invite to new Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, google-workspace-for-business

A coworkers emails were being sent to spam when emailing people outside of our organization. This was because someone previously had the same email as her in our system and must have gotten flagged as spam by a client or something.

To fix this, she made a new email with a unique name instead of taking over the previous Rachel's email.

She is now having an issue where she is still being invited to events on her old rachel@ email instead of rach@. Is there a way to forward event invites from outside our org so that they go to her active email?

Answer (score 1):

### Notes

Based on what you have described I have provided 2 related but different employee email transition options.  You are now a bit ahead of me and may wish to stay with **Option 2** if you have created two separate Google Workspace accounts and prefer that.

You could also adapt the solutions based on your current status.

**! Temporary email delivery interruption Option 2 !**

- **Before** making **changes**, insure that there is a **filter in place** in Google Workspace **copying email** from the old address **to the new address**. I am not referring to an email forwarder setup by the employee in their Gmail account.
- **Option 2** requires you to **remove the old email address temporarily** in Google Workspace in order for it to be allowed to be added to the new employee.
- In **Option 1 the email address is never removed**.

### Alternate Email Address

1. If the old employee's email address is an **Alternate Email Address** of the new employee's Google Workspace account, you will get the behavior you want.
2. I would **not** advise the user to add it as an alias in their Gmail account settings (send-as, reply-as etc.), and I would remove it if they have done so since this introduces the possibility of sending email with the old email address which is not your goal, and is completely unnecessary for receiving all email intended for the old email address since this is handled by Google Workspace.

Moving forward all email directed to the old employee address will go to the new employee address.  All email from the new employee address, whether new messages or replies to messages that were addressed to the old employee, will be addressed from the new employee email.  Accepted calendar invites will populate in the new employee's calendar regardless which email address they were sent to etc.

---

### Option 1: Give new employee old employee's account

In Google Workspace (GWS) change the old employee's account information to match the new employee:

1. Navigate to [GWS Home](https://admin.google.com/ac/home) and click [Update a user's name or email](https://admin.google.com/ac/users?action_id=RENAME_USER). * *some alternatives below.*
2. Type the start of the **old employee's username**, then select them from the auto-complete list and click **Proceed**
3. Change the **name** as appropriate and also change the **Primary email** from **old**@employee.com **to new**@employee.com.
             **-->   Note:** GW will automatically add **old**@employee.com as an alias of **new**@employee.com when you change it.
4. Click **Done** after reading the dialog that pops up.
5. You will be left looking at the User's profile page and can make further changes as appropriate (e.g. Reset Password,

**Step 1 Alternatives**
GW has many ways to access the same functionality.  I have provided a couple of additional step 1. options to illustrate:

- Alternative 1 From the [**Users list** in GW](https://admin.google.com/ac/users), click the **Update User** link that appears when you **hover over the old employee's username**
- Alternative 2: From the [**Users** section of GW](https://admin.google.com/ac/users), **click the** old employee's **username**, then from their user page, click the **Update User** link on the left-hand side.

---

### Option 2: Create new employee account

In Google Workspace (GWS) create your new employee's account as you currently do with **new@employee.com** as their email address.

1. Navigate to [GWS Home](https://admin.google.com/ac/home) and click [Update a user's name or email](https://admin.google.com/ac/users?action_id=RENAME_USER).
2. Type the start of the **old employee's username**, then select them from the auto-complete list and click **Proceed**
3. You do not need to change the **name** but should change the **Primary email** from **old**@employee.com to a different address that does **not match** either **new**@employee.com or **old**@employee.com example: **quit**@employee.com.
             **-->   Note:** GW will automatically add **old**@employee.com as an alias of **quit**@employee.com when you change it.
4. Click **Done** after reading the dialog that pops up.
5. You will be in the old employee's (**quit**@employee.com) **User profile** page and should click **Add Alternate Emails**
6. **Delete** any **Alternate email addresses (email alias)** that you'd like to assign to the **new** employee and click **save**.
7. Return to the (all) [**Users** section of GW](https://admin.google.com/ac/users), click the **new** employee's **username** to switch to their user profile.
8. From the new employee's user profile page, click **Add Alternate Emails** and add in any aliases you removed from the old employee.

---

### Helpful Links

Google Workspace Home: https://admin.google.com/ac/home
Google Workspace Rename User: https://admin.google.com/ac/users?action_id=RENAME_USER
Google Workspace Users: https://admin.google.com/ac/users

---